# Forcing tikz externalization to recreate all images using arara

Tags: tikz-external, arara

I am using the externalization library of tikz to have most of the pictures compiled only once and just included in later LaTeX runs.

Once in a while I would like to redo all the images, for example after making changes to the font. To achieve this I used to manually delete the externalized files, OR adding the line `\tikzset{external/force remake}` somewhere before my first picture and commenting it for the future runs.

Since I just discovered `arara` I would love to have myself some automation `;)`

How do I achieve with `arara` to either

- delete the content of an entire folder, not knowing how many files are in there or what they're called or
- add a line of code in the `.tex` file for one single run, in this case: `\tikzset{external/force remake}`

Sorry, but I don't have a single clue on how to start with rules or directives. But this snippet could serve as a starting point

```
% arara: cleanfolder: { folder: tikzternalize }
% !arara: insertforceremake
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{tikzternalize/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some copy/pasting from existing rules and research I came up with a working solution, although I am not entirely happy with it...

Instead of removing all the files from an exisiting folder, I simply delete the directory and recreate it in the same place. Empty, of course.

```
!config
# Rule for deleting the contents of a folder with arara
identifier: cleanfolder
name: CleaningTool for a whole folder
commands:
 - <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c rmdir /s/q", "rm -f" ).concat(' "').concat(folder).concat('"') }
 - <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c md", "mkdir").concat(' "').concat(folder).concat('"') }
arguments:
 - identifier: folder
   flag: <arara> @{parameters.folder}
```

I would be very happy with any comment on this, for I think the problem could be solved a lot more "elegantly" than with what I produced.

### Update:

I even managed to address the second part of my question myself. Inspired by [Chris' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148113/22759) to [Using arara to compile powerdot twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148095/using-arara-to-compile-powerdot-twice) I modified the `pdflatex` rule that is shipped with `arara` to define some sort of `switch` command that triggers the desired action in the `.tex` file if the switch is correctly defined.

### rule: pdflatexwithswitch

```
!config
identifier: pdflatexwithswitch
name: run PDFLaTeX with specified switch and optional value
command: <arara> pdflatex @{action} @{draft} @{shell} @{synctex} @{options} "\def\@{switchname}{@{switchvalue}}\input{@{file}}"
arguments:
- identifier: action
  flag: <arara> --interaction=@{parameters.action}
- identifier: shell
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.shell,"--shell-escape","--no-shell-escape")}
- identifier: synctex
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.synctex,"--synctex=1","--synctex=0")}
- identifier: draft
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.draft,"--draftmode")}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
- identifier: switchname
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.switchname}
- identifier: switchvalue
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.switchvalue}
  default: 0
```

The rule in action:

### demo.tex

```
% arara: pdflatexwithswitch: { shell: yes, switchname: forceremake, switchvalue: doit }
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\forceremake}}{}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\forceremake}{doit}}{\tikzset{external/force remake}}{}}
```

I am much more content with this one. Comments still welcome.

Comment: It may be more convenient to use `mode=list and make` for the external library, which creates a makefile for generating the figures. To force the figures to be re-created, you'd need to use the `-B` flag (if memory serves me right) when running the makefile.

Comment: @sudosensei : thanks for the input. I can't, however, seem to get it to work that way. I use [Make for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) and when running `make -f demo.makefile` I get an error. Any hints?

Comment: I can try to help. `:-)` What error are you getting?

Comment: @sudosensei: here it is "process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat demo.figlist, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat demo.figlist, ...) failed. All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them."

Comment: That error looks closer to `C` than LaTeX -- weird. Maybe you should consider posting a new question?