# Compile document multiple times with different parameters

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I'd like to have different versions of my document. So far I built the document such that I only have to change

```
\newcommand{\setversion}{0}
```

to the version number I'd like and the respective document is compiled. However, I'd like that the document is compiled mutliple times automatically and with different `\setversion`-parameter. Is that possible and how?

I am using pdflatex by the way.

---

I found out that there are

- `latexmk mydoc.tex` [How can I avoid compiling twice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30330/how-can-i-avoid-compiling-twice)
- `rubber --pdf mydoc.tex`
- arara: [Using arara to compile powerdot twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148095/using-arara-to-compile-powerdot-twice) http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/arara/arara-usermanual.pdf

but I got kind of confuse how to do my simple case.

## Solution:

```
pdflatex '\newcommand{\setversion}{2}\input{yourfile}'
```

Comment: a commandline of `pdflatex '\newcommand\setversion}{2}\input{yourfile}'`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: While compiling my document with kile is no problem, your command has a couple of problems with my tikz-constructions. Not sure why. E.g. `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/semi thick' and I am goin
g to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: that is presumably an error in your document when the version is set to 2, impossible to say without an example

Comment: The key is `semithick` and not `semi thick`. No matter how you compile it, the latter will always give that error.

Comment: @cfr: I checked. You are right, it is `semithick`. Fun fact though: While it does not work using the pdflatex-command, it **does** work when I use Kile!

Comment: That's not a fun fact. That's misinformation, however sincerely you believe it. Kile does not compile your document. It can't. It is only an editor. It runs some binary with some arguments to compile your `.tex` file. Probably `pdflatex` by default. But no TeX engine will magically cause a PGF key to be recognised which has not been defined. Unless it is using different packages and you somewhere define this as a custom key and that definition is somehow loaded when Kile's command is executed but not when you run `pdflatex`.... Have you ill-advisedly set Kile's compile to continue past errors?

Comment: @cfr: Sorry, I expressed myself imprecise: I meant that when I compile it from Kile. I am well aware that Kile uses pdflatex. I didn't deliberately, searched for the settings, couldn't find it? Do you know were it is found?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Do you want to put this in an answer, to get accepted?

Comment: If you mean my comment that the question appears to be unanswerable no, If you fixed it that's good but I suggest we just close this as unclear in that case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Putting this question on hold is kind of iritating. Your answer `pdflatex '\newcommand{\setversion}{2}\input{yourfile}'` was perfectly fine - I just wanted to accept it as an answer.

Comment: sorry about that, still no harm done, you got the answer you needed. I'm sure the technique of defining a macro before input is already on site so once that was clearly what was meant the question would probably have been closed as duplicate anyway.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I like to accept some answer - if only to be able to track which of my problems still needs solving.